# inserting ampersand (&) in mysql with PDO php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm using PDO to insert values into mysql

I'm doing something like this

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(value) VALUES(?)");
$sql -> execute(array($value));
```

I noticed that if I type in the text `&` in my input field, it gets removed into inserting mysql. I guess this is good because it shows that mysql injection is protected? Well what if I would like to have just this value as a text such as : `beer & wine`

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: It shouldn't escape `&`. Is your string quoted in the query?

Comment: i just had what i wrote in the example. I have a question mark `?` no quotes?

Comment: You nee to wrap the `?` in quotes then.

Comment: You don't wrap `?` into quotes...and `&` has nothing to do with injections...

Comment: i dont think thats how PDO works. and i tried putting in quotes, but it doesn't insert into mysql anymore

Comment: how come & won't insert?

Comment: 1)Why the jQuery tag? I see no jquery there...I'll remove the tag; 2)Are you sure the `&` is getting discarded? Var_dump() the string when you fetch the 'value' field. Anyway, maybe I phrased it bad on my prev comment, but `?` (the placeholder) **mustn't** be enclosed in quotes

Comment: it has nothing to do with injection either

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this is good

This is apparently BAD. A database that cannot store certain symbols is a nonsense. Imagine one was used on this site. **You were unable to ask your question at all!**

> it shows that mysql injection is protected?

It shows nothing. An ampersand has nothing to do with injections and as I said above, removing symbols has nothing to do with injection protection.

> it gets removed into inserting mysql.

It doesn't. It is just as you are seeing it. You are seeing it **not in the database**, but somewhere else. That is your problem.

Check your data before insert.
Check your *database*. Find your ampersand untouched.
**Then trace your data flow to find the spot where ampersand is lost.**
Then ask a question.

Comment: Don't call it rude. It may be harsh but it is not rude. I don't care too much about wording, but for the person with big red button it's a triggering keyword. And yes, certain answers are better than evasive ones.